# ReactJS won't render to index.htm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Almost done learning React on Codecademy, so I wanted to start coding something in it on my PC. I have put the directory onto my XAMPP server, but the React app still won't render.

```js
class LandingPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h2>Hello</h2>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<LandingPage />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>ReactApp</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Mae" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="sass/design.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- import react, react-dom and babel-core -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div id="app">

  </div>


  <script type="text/babel" src="react-front.js"></script>
<!--Import jQuery-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where does `react-front.js` located? are you sure you're setting the right path?

Comment: @Yoav react-front.js is located in the same folder as index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think any browser by default understands JSX. You need to set up the chain to compile your source to pure JS.
If you only want to play around I recommend using the Create React App.
See: https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#creating-a-new-application

Comment: Babel has been set up in the above code as CDN. That is a valid way to run JSX code, although may not be ideal to do in production

Comment: Wasn't what I was asking for, but you are right, thank you @RetekBacsi